# Opening JqueryMobile Dialog via JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am trying to open a Jquery Mobile dialog via JS function but its not working for me 
here is the function

```
function showSettings()
{
 document.getElementById('settings').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('passwordView').style.display = 'block';
 $.mobile.changePage('#myPopupDialog', 'pop', true, true);
}
```

and here is the jsFiddle 
**http://jsfiddle.net/7C8Lw/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to differntiate between *Dialog* and *Popup* widgets. A *Dialog* is a *page* but in shape of a dialog. Hence, *Dialog* div should be placed outside page div.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <!-- content -->
</div>

<div data-role="dialog">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7C8Lw/1/)**